# Find item if it exists

Tags: c#, list

I have list with items and I check if an item exists in a List. If it exists, I try to find it.

I think that it has a little overhead, because I currently make two passes over the list. Is it possible to do in single pass?

Currently I have.

```
public partial class Item
{
    public string text;
    public int id;
}
....
static List<Item> data = new List<Item>();
static stub = new Item() { text = "NaN", id = -1 };
public static Item Get(int targetId)
{
    if (data.Any(f => f.id == targetId) == false)
    {
        return stub;
    }
    return data.Find(f => f.id == targetId);
}
```

I want something like

```
...
public static Item Get(int targetId)
{
    Item result;
    result = data.Find(f => f.id == targetId);
    if (result == null)
    {
        return stub;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you're asking, but it seems like you're looking for `FirstOrDefault()` I guess.

Comment: @CodeCaster However, if the data isn't unique it could return an incorrect.

Comment: Edit code to show what is `data`. Basic Find return null if can't find nothing?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be looking for [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb340482(v=vs.100).aspx):

```
Item _stub = new Item
{ 
    text = "NaN", 
    id = -1 
};

public Item FindByID(int id)
{
    // Find the first item that has the provided id, or null if none exist.
    var existingItem = data.FirstOrDefault(i => i.id == id);

    // When not found, return the _stub
    return existingItem ?? _stub;
}
```

You also may want to reconsider your naming conventions and whether you actually need these members to be `static`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks good. Static is Ok (`sub` and `data` is global read only entity for this class). Can't understand what's wrong with names.

Comment: @Stepan read [MSDN: Naming Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx) and especially [MSDN: Capitalization Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(v=vs.71).aspx). Public methods should in general be `PascalCased`. Also the method name `get` and its parameter named `i` aren't really descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`List.FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static Item get(int i)
{
    int index = data.FindIndex(item => item.id == i);
    if (index == -1) return stub;
    return data[index];
}
```

If it's actually an array you can use `Array.FindIndex`:

```
public static Item get(int i)
{
    int index = Array.FindIndex(data, item => item.id == i);
    if (index == -1) return stub;
    return data[index];
}
```

Comment: FindIndex() is good too. Can't understand how i missed this method.

Answer (score 0):

So `FirstOrDefault()` is the way to go. You can also use `SingleOrDefault()` if there is only supposed to be one item in that list.

```
    static stub = new Item() { text = "NaN", id = -1 };
    public static Item get(int i)
    {
        Item result;
        result = data.FirstOrDefault(f => f.id == i);

        if (result == null)
        {
            return stub;
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this:

```
return data.Find(f => f.id == i) ?? stub;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an extension method for exactly this purpose

```
public static T FirstOrSpecificDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, 
                                       Func<T, bool> predicate, T defaultValue)
{
     return list.FirstOrDefault(predicate) ?? defaultValue;
}
```

usage in your case would be

```
Item result = list.FirstOrSpecificDefault(f => f.id == i, stub);
```